# Is there a downside to enforcing 128bit SSL for a website

Tags: security, ssl, web-server, iis-7, https

On Windows Server 2008 R2 I can enforce 128bit SSL for a website by executing:

```
appcmd set config "Default Web Site" -section:access -sslFlags:Ssl,Ssl128 -commit:apphost
```

Is there a downside to that? Are there any reasons not to do this, or good reasons to always do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No reason not to do it, unless you know you have customers with ancient or government-restricted browsers that cannot do 128-bit encyrption. In 2012, you probably don't.

Comment: Hmm... it seems even IE6 has support for 128 bit encryption. Not sure whats left after that http://www.ehow.com/how_4966135_upgrade-internet-explorer-bit-encryption.html

Answer (score 2):

It's basically a tradeoff between security and performance. A 128-bit cipher will provide better performance (concurrency) than a 256-bit cipher but at a reduced level of security. In general though a 128-bit cipher has effective security.

Comment: I thought I'd ensure nobody uses _less_ than 128bit... I'll have to check whether this prevents 256bit, too.

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers have supported at least one 256bit cipher since  2006-2008. You can't assume 256bit for the general public yet (though you'd be blocking out a very small minority at this point), but you can safely assume 128bit is supported these days.

Also, there are 4 different 128-Bit ciphers that are commonly implemented (RC4, 3DES, AES, and Camellia). Each has pros and cons. RC4 is the fastest, and *probably* least secure. 3DES has problems up and down, and should be disabled in my opinion. AES and Camellia are fairly secure, though FIPS requires AES currently.